# using boost multi_index_container to preserve insertion order

Tags: c++, boost, multimap, multi-index

I initially started out using a `std::multimap` to store many values with the same key, but then I discovered that it doesn't preserve the insertion order among values with the same key.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595270/how-does-the-stls-multimap-insert-respect-orderings/1595473#1595473) claims it can be done with `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container`, but gives no example.  Looking through the docs, there are no examples of that usage, and I can't make heads or tails of how you're supposed to use this thing.  I have come to expect poor documentation from the lesser-used boost libraries, but this takes the cake.  Can anyone point me to a tutorial or example that shows it used the way I want, or perhaps even provide an example themselves?

Comment: Do you need this to be a multi-map?

Comment: yes, I do.  I have multiple values with the same key.

Answer (score 8):

You could achieve this by using `boost::multi_index` with two indices: `ordered_non_unique`(which allows values with the same key) and [`random_access`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnd_indices)(which will keep the insertion order).

```
struct some {
  long key;
  int data;
  int more_data;
  // etc.  
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  some, 
  indexed_by<    
    random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
    ordered_non_unique< member<some, long, &some::key> >
  > 
> some_mic_t;
```

Comment: Supporting this answer, from the boost documentation: **Random access indices are free-order sequences with constant time positional access and random access iterators. Elements in a random access index are by default sorted according to their order of insertion**

Comment: Gist: gist.github.com/dev-guy/7d5036204b5cfe4de7ba29aa48e11222

Answer (score -1):

How about a

```
map<int, vector<string> >
```

or

```
map<int, list<string> >
```

@Kirill: Good answer. I suspect Boost's random_access can be quite slow, as it will force all strings for all keys to be maintained in a single contiguous structure. Whereas the questioner simply wants order to be preserved within each key's set of mapped values.

Comment: `random_access` is an additional index. You use `ordered_non_unique` for search, then `random_access` for iterating through the resulting range. It is not slow.

Comment: (I've used multi_index a lot, but not random_index, so I'm not too certain about any of this)

@Kirill: Two points:

@rmeador wants to be able to "preserve the insertion order among values with the same key". Given a single key, how can the entire random index be used to quickly achieve this? I suspect that the structure I suggested may be the only way to do this.

and

I meant that the insertion of new elements may be slower than necessary, as the entire random index is potentially out of date.

Comment: @Kirill: To clarify, once the ordered_non_unique has identified a range of (unsorted) values corresponding to a single key, how do you then (quickly) use the random_access to sort that set of values? That set of values may be evenly spread throughout a large random_access index. Iterating across the random_access range will not keep the keys in order.