# Keep the order of unordered_map as we insert a new key

Tags: c++, c++11

I inserted the  elements to the `unordered_map` with this code:

```
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("A", 10));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("B", 11));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("C", 12));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("D", 13));
```

But when I used this command to print the keys

```
for (const auto i : myMap)
{
    cout  << i.first << std::endl;
}
```

they are not in the same order as I inserted them.

Is it possible to keep the order?

Comment: Part "unordered" in unordered_map should tell you something...

Comment: No. It's called "unordered" for a reason. If you need to maintain an order of insertion, you've chosen an unsuitable data structure. Use a vector of pairs, or something along these lines.

Comment: use another container to store your order

Comment: @Yuushi `std::map` maintains lexicographical order, not the order of insertion.

Comment: I need to search for the key, is there any better container for this purpose?

Comment: Searching for the key is provided by `std::unordered_map<T>::find()`.  Why do you also need to store insertion order?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik why "lexicographical" ? `Compare` template parameter defines order of keys and enumeration.

Comment: @c-smile I admit I simplified. A pedantically correct statement would be too long and would only serve to obscure the point I was trying to make, I felt.

Comment: Just use `std::vector` until it proves to be inefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not with an **unordered associative** data structure. However, other data structures preserve order, such as std::map which keeps the data sorted by their keys. If you search Stackoverflow a little, you will find many solutions for a data structure with fast key-based lookup and ordered access, e.g. [using boost::multi_index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240751/using-boost-multi-index-container-to-preserve-insertion-order).

If it is just about adding values to a container, and taking them out in the order of insertion, then you can go with something that models a queue, e.g. `std::dequeue`. Just `push_back` to add a new value, and `pop_front` to remove the oldest value. If there is no need to remove the values from the container then just go with a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 26):

No, it is not possible.

Usage of `std::unordered_map` doesn't give you any guarantee on element order.

If you want to keep elements sorted by map keys (as seems from your example) you should use `std::map`.

If you need to keep list of ordered pairs you can use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>>`.

Answer (score 4):

Remarkably common request without too many clean,simple solutions. But here they are:

1. The big library: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html Use unique index std::string (or is it char?) and sequenced index to retain the order.
2. Write it yourself using 2 STL containers: Use a combination of std::unordered_map (or std::map if you want sorted key order traverse as well) and a vector to retain the sequenced order. There are several ways to set this up, depending on the types on your keys/values. Usually keys in the map and the values in the vector. then the map is map<"key_type",int> where the int points to the element in the vector and therefore the value.

I might have a play with a simple template for a wrapper to tie the 2 STL containers together and post it here later...

I have put a proof of concept up for [review here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233157/wrapper-class-template-for-stdmap-stdlist-to-provide-a-sequencedmap-which):

I went with std::list to store the order in the end, because I wanted efficient delete. But You might choose std::vector if you wanted random access by insertion order.

I used a a list of Pair pointers to avoid duplicate key storage.