# Why unordered_map not showing correct index values of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, unordered-map

I have a string "codeforces" and now when i am storing characters of this string as key in an unordered map and index of occurrence of that character in a vector inside unordered map as value , then it is not showing correct indexes .

In this string "codeforces" character 'c' is occurring at index 1 and 8 , i would like to store character c as key in map and corresponding indexes of occurrences inside vector as value in unordered map . But when i am doing this it is not showing correct value . Can any body tell me why is this happening ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    string x = "codeforces";
    unordered_map<char,vector<int>> data;

    for(int i = 1;i <= x.size();i++){
        data[x[i]].push_back(i);
    }

    for(auto it : data){
        if(it.first == 'c'){
            vector<int> out = it.second;
            for(int j = 0;j < out.size();j++){
                cout<<out[j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output should be like this (for character 'c') -> 1 8 .

But it is showing -> 7 .

Comment: No, output should be 7 since you skip the first 'c' that is at index 0. Your 1st loop should be ` for(int i = 0;i < x.size();i++)` , then you should get the correct result of 0 7.

Comment: See [C++11: does unordered_map/set guarantees traversing order as insert order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389732/c11-does-unordered-map-set-guarantees-traversing-order-as-insert-order)

Comment: Indexing in C++ and most of programming is zero based (the first element of a sequence has index 0, not 1).

Comment: Thank you very much all of you , now i am getting correct answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `for` loop has a wrong range. You start at element `1` and because of `<=` only stop at the size of `codeforces + 1`, which is out of bounds.

When iterating arrays the index **starts at `0` and should end at `size() - 1`**. This can be easily achieved by saying `< size()` as the less operator will result in `false` if the index is at `size()` - therefore `size() - 1` is the last iteration step.

---

You have two options, either go from `1` to `size()` and access `[i - 1]`

```
for(int i = 1; i <= x.size(); i++){
    data[x[i - 1]].push_back(i);
}
```

or go from `0` to `size() - 1` and `push_back(i + 1)`

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
    data[x[i]].push_back(i + 1);
}
```

I recommend the latter, as it's the common way to iterate arrays.

---

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you should avoid writing `using namespace std;`.

Comment: there is no difference between `size` and `length`, they return the same value

Comment: only with different encoding they may differ

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number even for multibyte encoding (like UTF8) `length` still returns number of code units, not amount of characters. In fact, both `length` and `size` are defined simultaneously and share that definition in the Standard.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I check only one of them and found a note about UTF8, but then didnt check the other ;) Thanks