# Does multimap guarantee that insertion order matches the order of elements given in its initializer?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

If I do this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<char, int> m;

    m.emplace('a', 100);
    m.emplace('b', 200);
    m.emplace('b', 201);
    m.emplace('c', 300);

    for (const auto& p : m)
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << '\n';
}
```

… then, [since C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337612/560648), I'm guaranteed that the element with value `200` will precede the element with value `201`.

But what if I do this?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<char, int> m{
       {'a', 100},
       {'b', 200},
       {'b', 201},
       {'c', 300}
    };

    for (const auto& p : m)
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << '\n';
}
```

Are we guaranteed that "insertion order" matches the order of elements in the initialiser?

[A quick test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/468b3cc1aa6dabdd) gives encouraging results, but doesn't really prove anything.

I'm writing C++17.

*(I could switch to `std::map` with a compound key, but I have thousands of these things managed by a common interface, and only a few contain duplicate keys so I'm hesitant to introduce that complexity overall.)*

Comment: Looks like you hit another gray area

Comment: I cannot find any such guarantee in the current draft. Is it really there as claimed?

Comment: @n.m. Seems to be [`[associative.reqmts]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#4)? Plus the semantics for `emplace` described in table 69 below it

Comment: Because you never know when an implementation is going to randomly shuffle the elements from an initialiser list before iterating through them in a constructor...

Comment: @Galik Well, if it's not guaranteed, then that's precisely so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[associative.reqmts]](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#8):

> ... i and j satisfy
>   input iterator requirements and refer to elements implicitly convertible to value_type, [i, j) denotes a
>   valid range ... il designates an object of type `initializer_list<value_type>` ...
>
> ```
> Expression    Assertion/note
>               pre-/post-condition
>
> X(i,j,c)      Effects: Constructs an empty container
>               and inserts elements from the range [i, j)
>               into it; uses c as a comparison object.
>
> X(i,j)        Effects: Same as above, but
>               uses Compare() as a
>               comparison object.
>
> X(il)         same as X(il.begin(), il.end())
> ```

So, the effects being the same, ordering guarantees are same when constructing from an initialiser list, as they are when inserting a range of iterators.

Being input iterators, the range cannot *in general* be iterated out of order.

Comment: The pedantic side of me wants to say that `inserts elements from the range [i, j)` only specifies the bounds of the range, not the order in which it has to be iterated.

Comment: @Ics Very pedantically yeah, the order is unspecified. That appears to apply to pretty much all operations that insert from a range of iterators into any container. It would be pretty infuriating if for example `vector.insert(first, last)` didn't insert in order.

Comment: I would expect `[i,j)` to be defined to include an order property somewhere in the text, or, more likely, in a normative reference to some obscure mathsy standard

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit at least, the iterator category is only requried to be input iterator, which doens't provide any way of iterating non-linearly. But I haven't found an explicit rule saying that it couldn't do silly things with forward or more able iterators.

Comment: Found it in ISO 80000-2:2009 section 6, which [C++ refers to normatively](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.refs#1.10), and it is _not_ defined as an n-tuple but as a set, so order isn't technically well-defined. Dafuq

Comment: Yeah, even with forward iterators you could do even indices first, then odd. Doubtful anyone *would* though